# Словно дерево с листа

Tags: поэзия

**Голова моя пуста,

Как пустынные места,

Я куда-то улетаю,

Словно дерево с листа.**

Это стихи Г. Шпаликова, песня на его слова прозвучала в фильме "Я шагаю по Москве".

Меня интересует необычное сравнение (обычно лист улетает с дерева). Что оно означает и как назвать такой художественный прием?

https://kulturologia.ru/blogs/050817/35526/

Comment: А можно я стихи разобью на строчки? Да, интересный вопрос, молодец, что заметили. :)

Comment: Можно.  А как это сделать?

Comment: Чтобы перенести на следующую строчку, надо сделать двойной пробел и нажать Enter (у Вас не хватало только второго пробела). А если хотите пропустить целую строчку, никаких пробелов не надо, просто два Enter-а. Есть ещё какой-то тег для переноса (возможно, /br/ от ‘break’), но мне хватает и этого способа.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, оказывается, всё просто.

Comment: Да, просто! ;) Так что не стесняйтесь спрашивать о том, о чём я знаю или могу знать (имею в виду техническую сторону). Но некоторые в этом разбираются гораздо лучше. :))

Answer (score 1):

Лист и дерево. Может быть, дерево — не дерево, а рисунок дерева на листе. Может, здесь есть намёк на не сохранившийся фотоснимок, пострадавший, чернильный или карандашный, рисунок (след от отечественного цветного карандаша, например, на свету за год-другой полностью выгорал — улетучивался, а чернила запросто смывались духами).

Comment: Какая оригинальная и интересная у Вас трактовка, как у художника. А мне кажется. что здесь инверсия смысла: если лист улетает с дерева, то они расстаются, и еще неизвестно, кто улетает, а кто остается.  Но в любом случае здесь вроде бы присутствует пустота, чистое сознание как следствие разрыва связей. А вот каких связей, чего с чем?

Comment: @Sharon, это же чистой воды спекуляции. Каких связей, чего с чем... Стихи есть стихи, зачем их раскладывать на составные части? Просто неожиданность: у всех лист летит с дерева, а у него наоборот. И все, других смыслов нет, этого достаточно, один этот перевертень, без "объяснения", уже вызывает эстетическое чувство. Ну, должен вызывать, по крайней мере.

Comment: Ну не трактовка, конечно (не критик, никакой ни вед) — попытка как-то объяснить себе с точки зрения въевшегося в нутро соцреализма. Конечно, у Шпаликова здесь всё далеко не рационально: среда переходит в понедельник: Марк Шагал отдыхает.

Comment: @Niemand А зачем вообще стихи анализируют, художественные средства определяют? Читали бы себе и получали эстетическое чувство, у каждого своё. Наверное, хотят эти чувства сравнить, поделиться впечатлениями. А вдруг Ваше чувство недостаточно глубокое, поверхностное, так сказать? Может быть, Вы что-то не заметили, недопоняли.

Comment: Художественные средства определять – это одно, это делают литературоведы и другие "чернорабочие литературы" (литературные критики и т.п.) Но вы-то делаете несколько другое.

Comment: А Вы что делаете? Вмешались, не дали поговорить с интересным человеком. Участник Вы не новый, но приходится напоминать Вам правила. Хотите ответить на вопрос(в нем два пункта) - пожалуйста, но это не здесь. Хотите уточнить суть вопроса - тоже пожалуйста и тоже не здесь. А здесь можно дополнить мнение отвечающего, но Вы, кажется, не собираетесь это делать: то ли вопрос Вас не устраивает, то ли еще что. Так что Вы уж определитесь как-нибудь и разместите свое сообщение там, где следует.

Answer (score 1):

Стихотворение Г. Шпаликова  мне теперь представляется  еще более необычным (мне оно нравится в исполнении Никитиных).

Мне кажется, что перед нами (несмотря на внешнюю простоту и непритязательность) своеобразный опыт **смешения сознания во времени и пространстве, где всё сосуществует.**

**Направо и налево** — одно и то же, восприятие мира переходит от предмета к предмету, будто доска качается.

И жизнь **человека изображена в разных ракурсах**: великий поэт и в то же время обычный человек, а то и вовсе — никто.

**Дом жилой — и человек тоже (по)жилой?** Будто в нем кто-то долго жил (в этом образе).

**А время движется** не вперед, а только по кругу, да еще в разных направлениях: от среды до понедельника или от понедельника до среды, **вперед или назад**? И считать можно по-разному:  **дома** — лето,  **на улице** —  среда.

Если обо всем задуматься, то действительно можно испытать **пространственно-временной парадокс.** Хорошее упражнение для очистки сознания **(голова моя пуста**...).

Я шагаю по Москве,

Как шагают по доске.

Что такое? – сквер направо

И налево тоже сквер.

Здесь когда-то Пушкин жил,

Пушкин с Вяземским дружил,

Горевал, лежал в постели,

Говорил, что он простыл.

Кто-то, я не знаю – кто,

А, скорей всего, никто,

У подъезда на скамейке

Человек сидит в пальто.

Человек он пожилой,

На Арбате дом жилой, –

В доме летняя еда,

А на улице – среда

Переходит в понедельник

Безо всякого труда.

Голова моя пуста,

Как пустынные места,

Я куда-то улетаю

Словно дерево с листа.